# ProcessStartInfo.Arguments accept multiple arguments with double quotes

Tags: c#, process.start, wix3.11

```
string CandlePath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WiX Toolset v3.11\\bin\\candle.exe";
string BundlePath = "C:\\Solution Directory\\Bundle.wxs";
string wixObjPathToSave = "C:\\Solution Directory\\Bundle.wxs";
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe"); 
processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
processStartInfo.Arguments ="/k \"" + candlePath + "\" " +BundlePath + " " +wixObjPathToSave;
```

When I pass arguments like above, The process is accepting the arguments but candle.exe gives error that 'C:\Solution' is not recognized as internal or external command which is expected because i didnt provided double quotes to bundlePath and wixobjPathToSave

```
processStartInfo.Arguments ="/k \"" + candlePath + "\" \"" +BundlePath + "\" \"" + wixObjPathToSave +"\"";
```

When I pass arguments like above, The process gives error that 'C:\Program' is not recognized as internal or external command.

What I had done wrong?

Comment: In the above code snippet      string wixobjPathToSave ="C:\\Solution Directory\\Bundle.wixobj";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer

```
processStartInfo.Arguments ="/k \"\"" + candlePath + "\" \"" +BundlePath + "\" \"" + wixObjPathToSave +"\"";
```

I added one more extra double quote at front. Now its working fine. But i have only one doubt why an extra double quote is required?